# I need to create a circle using OGR and C# bindings.

Tags: gdal, c#, ogr

I have a reference point in latitude and longitiude. I need to create a circle in C# using GDAL and see if my list of points/polygons lie within the newly created circle. Is there a simple approach to doing this?

Answer (score 1):

My approach was this:

```
string pointlineString = "POINT (" + longitude + " " + latitude + ")";
Geometry centerOfCircle = Ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(ref pointlineString, GeoSys);
Geometry bufferDefination = centerOfCircle.Buffer(radiusInMiles, 100);
Geometry bufferDefnPolygonRef = bufferDefination.GetGeometryRef(0);
Geometry realCircle = Ogr.ForceToPolygon(bufferDefnPolygonRef);
```

I am essentially forcing the buffer points of the circle to render a polygon. You can smooth-en the circle by adding more points instead of 100. Hope this helps out someone.